# Ruby on Rails: Voyeur gem never completes command due to ffmpeg hanging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, process, system

I'm trying to allow users to upload a video to my RoR app, then convert it into all the formats necessary for HTML5 video. I have found a solution using the [Voyeur gem](https://github.com/devthenet/voyeur), which works for the most part. However, when I run the command to convert the video into html5 formats:

`videos = Voyeur::Video.new(filename: file_path).convert_to_html5(output_path: "#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp")`

Or even if I try to do it individually:

`mp4_vid  = Voyeur::Video.new(filename: file_path).convert(to: :mp4, output_path: "#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/processed_videos")
  ogv_vid  = Voyeur::Video.new(filename: file_path).convert(to: :ogv, output_path: "#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/processed_videos")
  webm_vid = Voyeur::Video.new(filename: file_path).convert(to: :webm, output_path: "#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/processed_videos")`

Anytime any command is sent to voyeur, it hangs for long periods of time and essentially locks up the program. I went into Activity Monitor (using OSX Lion), and found out the ffmpeg process is still running, but at 0% CPU. When I kill the process, the command completes and the video works fine.

Is there anyway in my code to check for a 0% CPU ffmpeg process, or is there some other way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem, the first thing to do is to be sure that you are using the right gem by including in your Gemfile

```
gem 'voyeur', :git => 'git://github.com/devthenet/voyeur.git'
```

And use voyeur as follows:

```
Voyeur::Media.new(...)
```

Next, if you're using `delayed_job_active_record`, be sure to add `delayed_job` as well

```
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

Those changes have to solve the problem. At least for me it helped.